# How to use GetListitems web service?

Tags: web-services

I'm trying to reach out to a calendar, look for the item with the number 10 inside of column ABCD, and then tell me the item ID for that item.

I'm using a workflow that calls a web service to reach out to the target list.

I'm obviously doing something wrong but I have no idea what it is. Someone, please help me out here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
        <listName>CalendarPublish</listName>
        <viewName></viewName>
        <query>
            <Where>
                  <Eq>
                     <FieldRef Name='ABCD' />
                     <Value Type='Integer'>10</Value>
                  </Eq>
           </Where>
        </query>
        <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        </ViewFields>
        <rowLimit>100</rowLimit>
        <webID></webID>
    </GetListItems>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The actual working code is below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" > <soap:Body> <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <listName>CalendarPublish</listName>
    <query>
    <Query>
    <Where>
    <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="ABCD"></FieldRef>
    <Value Type="text">10</Value>
    </Eq>
    </Where>
    </Query>
    </query> 
    <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" >
    </FieldRef> 
    </ViewFields>
    <QueryOptions> 
    </QueryOptions>
    </GetListItems>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Could you try this ? 
var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems 
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>CalendarPublish</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='ABCD' /> \
 <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
  </viewFields> \
  <query> \
   <Query> \
<Where> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='ABCD' /> \
     <Value Type='Integer'>"+qry+"</Value> \
  </Contains> \
  </Where> \
</Query> \
  </query> \
   </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Comment: Perhaps I should specify. I'm using a workflow that calls a web service to reach out to the target list. Maybe I'm wrong but this doesn't look like normal XML? Either way, I tried it. It didn't work.